# How do I recognise if a variable's object type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I am trying to learn debugging Javascript in Chrome's Javascript console. However, I don't understand how the console displays the data type of an object . For instance, in the Javascript Console, it shows this:

[image]

In this picture, I am using JQuery. I tried to do a `console.log` on a few variables but how do I know if a particular variable is a JQuery object or a raw DOM object? Is the `HTMLDivElement` or the other one that shows the `div` tag  listed in the console a JQuery object or a raw DOM object?

In general, how should I know the data type of an object or variable in Javascript in a debugger console like the Chrome's Javascript console? In languages such as Java, the data type of a variable is shown clearly in the debugger; I can know from the debugger what kind of object the variable is, whether it is an instance of `Class A` or instance of `Class B`, etc.

Comment: If you really want to inspect the properties of an object, use `console.dir`.

Comment: @naveen In fact, before I made an edit to my question, I really wanted to ask about inspecting the data types of Javascript during debugging in general. But I didn't have a more concrete example to use in my question. I could only thought of the JQuery and DOM object situation. And so I thought I put it this way.

Comment: @xenon. ok. sorry that i cannot undo my vote i guess.

Comment: @naveen No problem, it's okay. I should have phrased my question in a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (variable instanceof jQuery) // Or variable.jquery 
    // jQuery object.
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zwUcf/)

`instanceof` docs on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

> The instanceof operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor.

---

The way jQuery checks for DOM elements is with `nodeType`:

```
// Handle $(DOMElement)
if ( selector.nodeType ) {
```

The way jQuery checks for jQuery object is with the `jquery` property:

```
// HANDLE: $(expr, $(...))  
else if ( !context || context.jquery ) {
```

Comment: why not `if( elm.jquery ) `for jQuery object and `if( elm.nodeType )` for DOM object? :)

Comment: +1: even though its a duplicate question , you gave OP another method :)

Comment: @gdoron Thanks! I am still a little confuse. I was trying the code at http://jsfiddle.net/7jxFX/2/. There, I had one which was a jquery selector and the other the conventional javascript way. But both logged the same thing on the Javascript Console in Chrome. Should the first one, `$('contact')` a JQuery object but the second one, which was through `getElementById`, a raw DOM object?

Comment: @xEnOn. It's just the way the console works. [try this fiddle instead](http://jsfiddle.net/7jxFX/3/)

Comment: Thanks! So in general, does it mean that the only way to clearly know the data type of a variable or object in Javascript is through a `if` and `instanceof` check? Is there a way like in Java, C++, etc, where their data type of a variable or object is shown clearer in the debugger?

Comment: @xEnOn. Yes, the ways to check is `variable.prototype` or `variable instnaceof Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

Those are both jQuery objects.

The console recognizes them as array-like objects containing DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can view the type in the debugger if you go to **Scripts** tab.
then on the right press on the **+** sign under **Watch Expressions** and add whatever you like.
[image: inspector]

Answer (score 0):

JQuery objects are actually arrays of DOM elements, Weile DOM elements are just DOM elements.